# I have problem sharing files between ubuntu-server and Windows XP machine using SWAT

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, share

I installed SWAT with its wonderful GUI (with all of its 8 buttons)on my ubuntu-server machine the other day. I have a small network of 4 machines at home. In addition to my ubuntu-server, a windows XP, a debian laptop, and also an ubuntu-desktop machine.

But still I am unable to share files between my ubuntu-server and windows XP machines.

I have never done networking before, not even between windows machines, since I only have one windows machine anyway, but this time around I am trying to learn to do networking between these two machines first and eventually between all 4 machines.(Win XP and ubuntu-server)

What am I doing wrong?
before installing SWAT, I had struggled with samba file (smb.conf)for a while and failed to produce any results. I still have a copy of my original smb.conf file which I saved under smb.conf.copy name.

Regards,

Mansour

Comment: I suspect very few of us have an experience with the swat.  I am a bit surprised that you say things didn't work.  Ubuntu will create a read-only homes share by default.  Did the default shares work?

Comment: Thank you Khaled for your comment. No the default shares won't show on windows XP browser. I also tried two other methods, I typed in the Run: \\192.168.1.101\share   and   also  My Computer: Map The Network Drive:   None of these worked.   Mansour

Answer (score 0):

You mention you tried samba and it did not work. Take a look at this tutorial if you haven't already:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-10.04-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend

It should be rather straightforward. If you run into problems, try troubleshooting - this is an excellent checklist from samba itself:

- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/diagnosis.html

Comment: Thank you icyrock.com for your link, it seems like a very useful link, I'll try it and report back to you on this page, what was the result. I realized after posting here that I was not supposed to be posting here. I am an IT professional, just not managing a network yet. So I hope members of this forum would forgive me for my lack of attention to your FAQ section before posting, or I would not have posted the first time. Mansour